# Specifying column widths without wrapping in extra columns

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, navigation, bootstrap-5

I have the below HTML / CSS for a navbar using Bootstrap.

See also the screengrab of how I'd like it to look, basically I want the nav to line up to the left side of `#three` and also for it to be the same width as it.

[image: SCREENGRAB]

I'm trying to avoid wrapping it in a `col-md-4` however because it messes up the mobile nav in the WP theme that I'm using.

Is it possible to align them simply by adding any other classes or styles to the existing elements?

```
<html>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css" type="text/css" />
    <style type="text/css">
        
        #nav-main {
            background-color: blue;
        }

        #nav {
            background: red;
        }

        #three {
            background-color: green;
        }

        #header-top div div {
            padding-top: 30px;
            font-weight: bold;
        }

    </style>
    <body>



        <div id="page" class="site">

            <header id="masthead" class="site-header">
    
                <div class="fixed-top bg-light">
                    <div id="header-top" class="container">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-4">
                                01
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-4">
                                02
                            </div>
                            <div id="three" class="col-md-4">
                                03
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>




        <nav id="nav-main" class="navbar navbar-expand-lg">

            <div class="container">

                <!-- Navbar Brand -->
                <div>
                    <a class="navbar-brand md" href="#">
                        LOGO
                    </a>
                </div>


                <div id="nav" class="d-none d-md-block">
                    
                    <ul id="bootscore-navbar" class="navbar-nav ">
                        <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page nav-item nav-item-49">
                            <a href="#" class="nav-link ">ONE</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page nav-item nav-item-49">
                            <a href="#" class="nav-link ">TWO</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page nav-item nav-item-49">
                            <a href="#" class="nav-link ">THREE</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page nav-item nav-item-49">
                            <a href="#" class="nav-link ">FOUR</a>
                        </li>
                        </ul>
                    
                </div>

            </div><!-- .container -->

        </nav>

        </div>
    </header>
</div>
        




    </body>
</html>
```

I've tried `.ms-auto` but that just aligns it to the right... also I've tried wrapping them in extra columns but it stops the mobile nav from opening up

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Title</title>
  <!-- Required meta tags -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

  <!-- Bootstrap CSS v5.2.1 -->
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
    integrity="sha384-iYQeCzEYFbKjA/T2uDLTpkwGzCiq6soy8tYaI1GyVh/UjpbCx/TYkiZhlZB6+fzT" crossorigin="anonymous">


    <style>
        .navbarRight { padding-right:0 !important; }
        .navbarRight { padding-left:0 !important; }
    </style>



</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <!-- place navbar here -->


    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-4 bg-primary">
            Logo
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-4 bg-secondary">
            Navbar Menu
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="container navbarRight">
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-md-3 bg-info">
                    one
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-md-3 bg-danger">
                    two
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-md-3 bg-warning">
                    three
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-md-3 bg-primary">
                    four
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>


  </header>

  <main>

  </main>
  <footer>
    <!-- place footer here -->
  </footer>
  <!-- Bootstrap JavaScript Libraries -->
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.11.6/dist/umd/popper.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-oBqDVmMz9ATKxIep9tiCxS/Z9fNfEXiDAYTujMAeBAsjFuCZSmKbSSUnQlmh/jp3" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </script>

  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.1/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-7VPbUDkoPSGFnVtYi0QogXtr74QeVeeIs99Qfg5YCF+TidwNdjvaKZX19NZ/e6oz" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: check my codes with FullScreen mode

Comment: Thanks but that appears to put everything on the same line? I'd still like the navigation to be below the text above it